# Adding list of values in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, list

I'm searching for the option to use lists in a model of the ModelBuilder under ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap 10.X, I could right-click on the variable - properties - and under "this variable contains" change the toggle to "A list of values". I cannot find a similar function in ArcGIS Pro.

I explicitly do not search for iterators!

In ArcMap it looked like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you add a variable to the model you need to tick on **Multiple values** as shown below.

[image: Adding a variable to model builder1]

Comment: thanks a lot. But how can I make this a list of input variables. I can only set the new multi values-variable as a precondition for a tool but not as input. I'm not sure if this is exactly what I was looking for. I added an image to my original post.

Comment: As you have not explained what the Puffer tool is and what its input requirements are then I can only guess that you need to set the data type for your variable?

Comment: ah sorry, "Puffer"-tool is simply the "Buffer"-tool which is called "puffer" in German language. Sorry, that I did not gave you all the information but the image above is just an example of lists. Thanks!